# Как авторизоваться в Cisco any connect на ПК с python

Tags: python

Возможно ли написать скрип для ввода кредов в по автоматом ?[image: cisco]

Comment: Возможно. У него в поставке есть клиент командной строки - vpncli.exe. Чтобы авторизоваться при помощи него и простого bat-файла с перенаправлением ввода хватит.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

могу посоветовать использование данной библиотеки pywinauto https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Я думаю, что она поможет Вам в написании скрипта)